# Upgrading Ubuntu 13.09 to 13.10 for LTS?

Tags: package-management, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my ubuntu installation so I can begin working with mod_mono for apache. I tried to the usual upgrade command but I am getting some odd results. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
root@cubietruck:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linaro
Description:    Linaro 13.09
Release:        13.09
Codename:       raring


root@cubietruck:~# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1134 kB]
Fetched 1134 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'saucy.tar.gz' against 'saucy.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'saucy.tar.gz'
Can not run the upgrade
The error message is 'No such file or directory'.
root@cubietruck:~#
```

**python-apt:**

```
python-apt - Python interface to libapt-pkg
python-apt-common - Python interface to libapt-pkg (locales)
python-apt-dbg - Python interface to libapt-pkg (debug extension)
python-apt-dev - Python interface to libapt-pkg (development files)
python-apt-doc - Python interface to libapt-pkg (API documentation)
python-aptdaemon - Python 2 module for the server and client of aptdaemon
python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets - Python 2 GTK+ 3 widgets to run an aptdaemon client
apt-p2p - apt helper for peer-to-peer downloads of Debian packages
python-aptdaemon-gtk - Transitional dummy package
python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets - Python GTK+ 2 widgets to run an aptdaemon client

root@cubietruck:~# apt-get install python-apt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-stdlib python python-minimal python2.7
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk python-apt-dbg python-gtk2 python-vte python-apt-doc
  python2.7-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-stdlib python python-apt python-minimal
  python2.7
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2940 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9927 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libpython2.7-stdlib libpython-stdlib python2.7 python-minimal python
  python-apt
Authentication warning overridden.
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ raring/main libpython2.7-stdlib armhf 2.7.4-2ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ raring/main libpython-stdlib armhf 2.7.4-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ raring/main python2.7 armhf 2.7.4-2ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ raring/main python-minimal armhf 2.7.4-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ raring/main python armhf 2.7.4-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Err http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ raring/main python-apt armhf 0.8.8ubuntu6
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.4-2ubuntu3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python-defaults/libpython-stdlib_2.7.4-0ubuntu1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.4-2ubuntu3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python-minimal_2.7.4-0ubuntu1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python_2.7.4-0ubuntu1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/python-apt/python-apt_0.8.8ubuntu6_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**UPDATED:**

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Do you mean 13.04?  13.09 isn't a thing.  And 13.10 isn't LTS; 14.04 is.

Comment: See my updated question, it says 13.09?

Comment: No he is using Linaro. Linaro is not an official Ubuntu and they probably used a different naming.

Comment: if 'im not mistaken, support for none LTS version is limited to 2 years. Could it just be that the repo are no longer available ?

Answer (score 0):

Paste the output of `mount` if /tmp is mounted noexec then you need to remount it

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

Other then that try to run the following

```
sudo apt-get install python-apt
```

See if those clear up your problems.

**EDIT**

To get rarring apt-get working again add the following to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: mount returns nothing and I already have python3-apt

Comment: python-apt not python3-apt

Comment: No longer exists. Been deprecated and replaced by python3-apt. Also what does that have to do with upgrading from 13.09 to 13.10?

Comment: ubuntu still ships with 2.7 so you should have have python-apt   `apt-cache search python-apt`

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/python-apt

Comment: See my updated question. Getting 404 errors?

Comment: run a `apt-get clean all && apt-get update` then try the install

Comment: Still getting some errors, posted in my question.

Comment: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/ rarring isn't even there

Comment: ok makes sense since rarring is EOL and they removed all the packages.. we need to find a mirror that still has it to use

Comment: Yup, that's where I'm the most confused myself. No idea how any of this started happening now.

Comment: Yup, that's where I'm the most confused myself. No idea how any of this started happening now.

Comment: ok see my edit.. try adding those in.. then do a apt-get update and try the install

Comment: Yup, that's where I'm the most confused myself. No idea how any of this started happening now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17494/discussion-between-mike-and-kyle).